# Enviar correo desde PythonAnyWhere

Tags: python, servidor

```
import smtplib

import email
from smtplib import SMTP


def enviarDesdeHotemail(nuestroEmail,contrasena,destinoEmail,asunto,contenido):
    conn = SMTP('smtp.live.com', 587)
    conn.ehlo()
    conn.starttls()
    conn.ehlo()
    conn.login(nuestroEmail, contrasena)
    print("paso el loguin")
    msg = email.message_from_string(contenido)
    msg['From'] = nuestroEmail
    msg['To'] = destinoEmail
    msg['Subject'] = asunto
    conn.sendmail(nuestroEmail, destinoEmail, msg.as_string())
    conn.quit()
```

utilizando ese código que si  me funciona en mi consola local, en el servidor de PythonAnyWhere
salta el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 27, in <module>
    contenido="es es que envie desde dentro")
  File "prueba.py", line 9, in enviarDesdeHotemail
    conn = SMTP('smtp.live.com', 587)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

probé ver el estado de la conexión con `telnet smtp.live.com 587` y sale:

```
Trying 52.96.90.34... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

Alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo?, lo que necesito es enviar correos desde la plataforma de PythonAnyWhere.

Comment: prove ver el estado de la conexión con

Comment: `telnet smtp.live.com 587` y sale  `Trying 52.96.90.34...` `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`

Comment: puedes eliminar los comentarios, he editado la pregunta

Comment: Tienes un problema en la configuración de la red; no es un problema de código.

Comment: y hay alguna manera de solucionarlo? cambiar la configuración en la plataforma o algo?

Comment: La red de PythonAnywhere tiene cortafuegos que impiden que conectes a un servidor SMTP externo, salvo al de Google (para el cual han puesto una excepción en los routers). Otra solución es usar un servidor de correo que en vez de SMTP use HTTPS (y claro está estudiarse su api y acceder a ella mediante peticiones REST). Fuente https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/

Comment: gracias por la recomendación

Comment: me pueden recomendar alguna Api para servidores de correo que usen HTTPS